# How to regex replace tag followed by newline?

Tags: php, regex

I want to use preg_replace_callback to replace all instances of a custom tag with markup.  For instance, I'm using this code to replace instances of "[tube]...[/tube]":

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[tube\](.*)\[\/tube\]/', array('MyClass', 'mycallback'), $data);
```

The problem is it will not match this:

```
[tube]
http://www.somesite.com
[/tube]
```

How can I do this?

Note: Yes I am already familiar with the PECL bbcode extension, as well as the PEAR library.  But I want to do this without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use pattern modifiers.

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)   If this modifier is
>   set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters,
>   including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier
>   is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always
>   matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this
>   modifier.

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[tube\](.*)\[\/tube\]/smU', array('MyClass', 'mycallback'), $data);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: I tried this with preg_replace_callback('/\[tube\](.*)\[\/tube\]/s', ...);   But it doesn't give me what I want.  Note I am trying to capture the subexpression, but it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I think it should work. It is working for me. Try using /sm just in case to see if it works for you. Basically /s makes (.*) to match newlines as well

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching the end of line characters right now, try using

```
Pattern: \[tube\]\s([^\s]*)\s\[/tube\]
```

EDIT: Here's the code working on mine (`preg_match()` uses the same matching library as `preg_replace_callback()`

```
$val = '[tube]
http://www.somesite.com
[/tube]';

preg_match('|\[tube\]\s([^\s]*)\s\[/tube\]|', $val, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => [tube] http://www.somesite.com [/tube] [1] => http://www.somesite.com )
```

Comment: That does not match the example I gave.

Comment: Hmm, strange - tested it on mine and it works fine. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Looks like nl2br was getting in the way.  But this will not match the other case of [tube]...[/tube] without newlines, unlike the accepted answer.